# How to replace the namespace uri prefix and root element with xslt 2.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an XML file that contains elements qualified with namespace prefix and corresponding uri.

I want to do two things:

1. Replace the namespace uri and prefix with a different one throughout the xml:
   xmlns:urn="http://abcd" to xmlns:xsns="http://123"
   so that, `<urn:FirstELement>` becomes `<xsns:SecondElement>`
2. The root element needs to be replaced:
   `<urn:RootElementOld xmlns:urn="http://abcd">` to be replaced with `<xsns:RootElementNew xmlns:xsns="http://123">`

**Input XML(similar to actual):**

```
    <urn:RootElementOld xmlns:urn="http://abcd">
    <urn:FirstElement>
        <urn:FirstSubElement id1="abc" id2="efg">FirstValue</urn:FirstSubElement>
        <urn:SecondSubElement id3="hij" id4="klm">SecondValue</urn:SecondSubElement>
    </urn:FirstElement>
    <urn:SecondElement>
        <urn:ThirdSubElement id5="nop" id6="qrs">ThirdValue</urn:ThirdSubElement>
        <urn:FourthSubElement id7="tuv" id8="wxy">FourthValue</urn:FourthSubElement>
    </urn:SecondElement>
</urn:RootElementOld>
```

**Expected Output XML:**

```
    <xsns:RootElementNew xmlns:xsns="http://123">
    <xsns:FirstElement>
        <xsns:FirstSubElement id1="abc" id2="efg">FirstValue</xsns:FirstSubElement>
        <xsns:SecondSubElement id3="hij" id4="klm">SecondValue</xsns:SecondSubElement>
    </xsns:FirstElement>
    <xsns:SecondElement>
        <xsns:ThirdSubElement id5="nop" id6="qrs">ThirdValue</xsns:ThirdSubElement>
        <xsns:FourthSubElement id7="tuv" id8="wxy">FourthValue</xsns:FourthSubElement>
    </xsns:SecondElement>
</xsns:RootElementNew>
```

**My Output:**

```
    <xsns:RootElementOld xmlns:xsns="http://123">
    <xsns:FirstElement>
        <xsns:FirstSubElement id1="abc" id2="efg">FirstValue</xsns:FirstSubElement>
        <xsns:SecondSubElement id3="hij" id4="klm">SecondValue</xsns:SecondSubElement>
    </xsns:FirstElement>
    <xsns:SecondElement>
        <xsns:ThirdSubElement id5="nop" id6="qrs">ThirdValue</xsns:ThirdSubElement>
        <xsns:FourthSubElement id7="tuv" id8="wxy">FourthValue</xsns:FourthSubElement>
    </xsns:SecondElement>
</xsns:RootElementOld>
```

**My XSLT:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:urn="http://abcd"
    xmlns:xsns="http://123" exclude-result-prefixes="urn">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="xsns:{local-name(.)}" namespace="http://123">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}"> 
        <xsl:value-of select="." /> 
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="urn:RootElementOld">
        <xsl:element name="xsns:RootElementNew" namespace="http://123">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Could you please help me out? I am new to XSLT.

Comment: It appears your code does output the expected output, see https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y92/ and https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y92/1. So if you really get the wrong output please indicate how you run your XSLT.

Comment: True, when I run the xslt file on my eclipse, it works. But, when I run it on Redhat EAP 6.3(server), I am getting the wrong output indicated in my question.